# What does JUNIT do or test for in this program?

Tags: java, junit

What does JUnit do or test for in this program?

```
public class TestFailure extends TestCase {

        public static void test() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            JavaSourceViewer.writeURL2Stream("http://www.google.de", baos);
            assertTrue(baos.toString().contains("google")); //checks condition is true
        }
}
```

Comment: Look at the last line, it checks to see if the string `google` is present in the url.

Comment: @Dan Rather AT the URL.

Comment: @Gangnus Thanks, I changed that in my response.

Comment: I would remove `static` and give the test a more meaningful name, e.g. `testThatUrlContainsGoogle`

Comment: @Dan You are welcome.  Really, a test cannot be truly analyzed apart from the code being tested. So, it could be only a guess. But it seems to be an extract from a very frequent interview question (http://pastebin.com/58C0FKpj)

Comment: @vikingsteve rather testIfPageContainsString

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
assertTrue(baos.toString().contains("google"));
```

Checks to see if the string `google` is present at the URL that was provided in line above. I would recommend going through a [jUnit tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html).